# How i use dompdf with laravel without a wrapper

Tags: php, laravel, dompdf, laravel-cashier

I'm trying to use dompdf without the barryvdh's wrapper because I have laravel cashier installed on my project and get the message:

```
 - Root composer.json requires barryvdh/laravel-dompdf ^0.9.0 -> satisfiable by barryvdh/laravel-dompdf[v0.9.0].
    - Conclusion: don't install dompdf/dompdf v0.8.4 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install dompdf/dompdf v1.0.2 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install dompdf/dompdf v0.8.5 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install dompdf/dompdf v1.1.0 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install dompdf/dompdf v0.8.6 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install dompdf/dompdf v1.1.1 (conflict analysis result)
    - laravel/cashier is locked to version v10.7.1 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - laravel/cashier v10.7.1 requires dompdf/dompdf ^0.8.0 -> satisfiable by dompdf/dompdf[v0.8.0, ..., v0.8.6].
    - You can only install one version of a package, so only one of these can be installed: dompdf/dompdf[v0.8.0, ..., v0.8.6, v1.0.0, ..., v1.1.1].
    - barryvdh/laravel-dompdf v0.9.0 requires dompdf/dompdf ^1 -> satisfiable by dompdf/dompdf[v1.0.0, ..., v1.1.1].
    - Conclusion: don't install dompdf/dompdf v1.0.1 (conflict analysis result)
```

Whenever I tried to install the package. So I'm using the 0.8.6 version that ships with the cashier to generate my pdf. I made a simple test:

```
Route::get('manual-test-pdf', function () {
  $dompdf = new Dompdf();
  $html = view('pdf.test')->render();
  $dompdf->loadHtml($html);

  return $dompdf->stream();
});
```

Trying to render the view:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Pdf test</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Test one</h1>
</body>

</html>
```

But the result is always a blank page. `->render()` or `->stream()` gave the same result. I think I'm doing something wrong, but I didn't found anything online about the correct way of returning/rendering a pdf with pure dompdf since everyone uses barryvdh's version.

Can anyone give me a light on this one?

Comment: Seems you have a dependency that is using a lower version of it already, perhaps `composer update`

Answer (score 1):

The latest stable version of laravel/cashier as of this posting is [v13.7.0](https://github.com/laravel/cashier-stripe/blob/v13.7.0/composer.json) which requires:
`"dompdf/dompdf": "^0.8.6|^1.0.1"`.
`"php": "^7.3|^8.0"`

The latest stable version of barryvdh/laravel-dompdf as of this posting is [v0.9.0](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf/blob/v0.9.0/composer.json) which requires:
`"dompdf/dompdf": "^1"`
`"php": "^7.1 || ^8.0"`

It looks a lot like these packages are compatible with each other for recent PHP versions.

Your composer.json file already specifies:
`"barryvdh/laravel-dompdf": "^0.9.0"` 
But your composer.lock file is locking laravel/cashier to version v10.7.1.
So basically you just need to update your cachier version from v10.7.1 to a more recent build such as the current latest as of the time of this posting: v13.7.0 (you can specify this in your composer.json file)

You should be able to get by with a simple:
`composer update`.

You can also trying deleting your composer.lock file so you're not locked down to a specific version then retry installing/updating with either `composer install` or `composer update`.
If you need to retain any specific versions of something after deleting the composer.lock file, such as if it breaks code, specify them in your composer.json file.

**Edit:**

This sounds a lot like you already have laravel-dompdf version 0.8.6 installed, along with laravel/cashier version v10.7.1, and laravel 5, but you're tied down and not able to upgrade stuff at the moment. So unfortunately you're unable to grab laravel-dompdf version 0.9.0. But I don't think that would matter since you're on an older laravel installation.

I think you're just struggling with how to use laravel-dompdf version 0.8.6 which you already have installed:
https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf/tree/v0.8.6

You need to make sure you add the service provider to your laravel project's config/app.php file:
`Barryvdh\DomPDF\ServiceProvider::class,`

Scroll down to the `'providers' => [` section in the file and if it is missing, add the service provider line into there alongside the other service providers you are using.

The service provider provides the `dompdf` class.
But you NEED to make sure you are constructing it using laravel so it has a chance to handle creation so it can call the service provider.

I see you're trying to run:

```
Route::get('manual-test-pdf', function () {
  $dompdf = new Dompdf();
  $html = view('pdf.test')->render();
  $dompdf->loadHtml($html);

  return $dompdf->stream();
});
```

This will not go through the service provider....

As per the readme, you would need to run something like:

```
$pdf = \App::make('dompdf.wrapper');
```

You can also try:

```
$pdf = app('dompdf.wrapper');
```

That would handle the creation aspect and I'm sure you can figure it out from there.

In terms of trying to get something working, you can try testing with:

```
Route::get('manual-test-pdf', function () {
    $pdf = \App::make('dompdf.wrapper');
    $pdf->loadHTML('<h1>Test</h1>');
    return $pdf->stream();
});
```

Comment: I'm sorry for not specifying, laravel cashier version 10. Because the project uses laravel 5, so the newer version that works is the version 10, which uses dompdf v0.8.6. I can't update the whole project on the moment, so I need a workround to deal with pdfs on the moment.

Comment: @VitorRayan I updated my answer. Make sure you are constructing the class the laravel way so the service provider of the package has a chance to run.